# (SCSS) My media queries aren't working correctly with display: flex;

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm working with SCSS trying to create a responsive site. I'm using Koala to compile my code, and I have a styles.scss that is importing my other partial stylesheets. Certain styles do work dynamically on my site when changing the width, but with my display: flex; things aren't changing to what I want them to.

I've tried changing the media queries to nest inside of themselves, but nothing is working properly.

styles.scss

```
@import "reset";

@import "variables";

// @media only screen and (min-width: 1em) {
@import "small-default";
// }

//35em is also 560px (if basefont is 16px)
@media only screen and (min-width: 560px) {
@import "medium";
}

//64em is also 1028px (if basefont is 16px)
@media only screen and (min-width: 1028px) {
@import "large";
}
```

index.html

```
<div class="footer">
        <footer>
          <div class="info">
              <div class="contact">
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                <p>CABOT CRUIZES</p>
                <p>23 South Main St. Suite 16</p>
                <p>Lexington, VA 24450</p>

                <br>
                <h2>Phone:</h2>
                <p>1-800-555-1234</p>

                <br>

                <h2>Hours of Operation:</h2>
                <p>Monday - Friday 9am - 4pm</p>
              </div>

              <div class="newsletter">
                <h2>News Letter</h2>
                <p>Subscribe to our email list and stay up-to-date with our hottest offers and latest specials.</p>

                <div class="subscribe">
                    <input type="email" name="" id="subscribeEmail">
                    <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>  

              <div class="why">
                <h2>Why Cabot Cruises?</h2>
                <p>Cabot Cruises is a travel agency providing the best cruise deals on our online travel website. We can help you with all inclusive vacations including discounted cruises.</p>
                <br>
                <p>We do not sell travel to residents of Deleware, Iowa, Florida, Hawaii and Washington state because those states are just wierd. If you are a resident of one of these states, call your congressman and tell them to change the regulations. </p>
              </div>


        </footer>
      </div>
```

_small-default.scss

```
.footer {
  background-color: $secondaryColor;

  footer {
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 $gutter;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    color: $thirdColor;


    .info {
      margin: 0 auto;
      color: $thirdColor;

      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;




      .contact, .newsletter, .why {
        padding: .5rem 0;
      }

      .contact {
      }

      .newsletter {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;


        .subscribe {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;

          input{
            height: 35px;
            margin-bottom: .2rem;
          }

          button {
            height: 44px;
            background-color: #666;
            border-radius: 10px;
            color: #fff;
          }
        }
      }

      .why {
      }



      h2{
        margin-bottom: .75rem;
      }
      input {
        margin-top: .6rem;
      }
    }


  }
}
```

_medium.scss
(I'm just trying to do a simple direction change to the layout, but nothing is working.)

```
footer {

    .info {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello manuel.espinoza is there anymore relevant code we can look at to better assist you with this issue?  Also is there a particular reason you are using ems instead of pixels in your media queries?

Comment: I updated the code provided. Let me know if you need any further clarification. I also went with ems because it's a bit older code. I switched back to px and nothing changes.

Comment: Ok thank you,  I will take a look. just make sure you thoroughly test in safari before using ems

Comment: from just a quick glace you have it called out as .footer footer .info in your small.scss and footer .info in your medium.scss unless I am missing something your small is more specific than your medium.. I could be wrong if your going the other way..IE from medium to small

Comment: .footer is on the small.scss to establish some default styling, and on my medium I have footer there just empty in order to be easy to find, but I'm not setting any other styling at the moment beside just trying to change to the flex-direction of my .info. if that makes sense.

Comment: ok so you are going from a small device to a medium device if I understand you correctly

Comment: Unless I am missing something or just don't understand it should just be because the rule of specificity won't allow it to change from column to row.  Let me know if you have anymore problems, questions or it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would be

```
.footer {
  footer {
     .info {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
.footer footer .info {
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

if you would like to call it the same way you did in your medium.scss

Comment: So that worked. Are you not able to reference objects directly? My question is why wouldn't it work if I just referenced .info?

Comment: rule of specificity.  If you have previously referenced something as .footer footer .info and declared your css (for example padding: 1px...) then later you try to change the padding the way you reference it needs to be the same or more specific than how you referenced it the first time. So had you referenced it as .info in your small scss you could then just reference .info in your medium.scss and it would have worked. let me know if that does not make sense.  If you look at my two examples above they are exactly the same.. once scss is compiled to css

Comment: that makes perfect sense, I was just trying to bypass everything from before, and it wasn't working properly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: no problem boss, please smash that check mark if we are all done here.  Please and thank you